# Nothing happening when running "sxa init"

Tags: sxa

hoping someone can help. I have successfully installed the SXA CLI as the pre-perquisites to setting up an SXA theme in Sitecore 10.1, I'm following the next steps but hitting a snag I think when trying to run "`sxa init`".

[image]

It has been hanging on this message for a while now because I'm not sure what to expect from this task, is this normal? does it just take time? or is something wrong? Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated `gulp version` to at least `4.0.0` on the project. This solved the issue.